# Find a word in a TextBox1 and if it found add the line to TextBox2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First I read the TextBox1 using TextReader than tried to find a string 'flag' in TextBox1

```
 TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(TextBox1.Text);
            int rows = 5000;

            string[] text1 = new string[rows];
            for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++)
            {
                text1[r] = read.ReadLine();
            }

            string flag = "healthy";
            string[] readText = text1;
            foreach (string s in readText)
            {
                if ((s.Contains(flag) == true))
                {
                    TextBox2.Text = s.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox2.Text = "Not Found";
                }
            }
```

than I got this error [[image]]

I want the program to find a keyword in a TextBox lines if the program finds it write the keyword with the whole line into another textbox TextBox2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No, cause I want to do this in Asp.Net C#  and want to find a string value in  TextBox and not a Gridview. When the teh algorithm finds the string in a whole text it should add the whole line( which contains the string too) to add in TextBox2...

Comment: What would be an easy method to find a string in a textbox and select the line and add the whole line to another textbox? (in ASP.NET C#)

Comment: `s` is null .. what did you not unerstand? [obviously because nature of `ReadLine`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ri8BG)

Comment: Selvin
 sorry I am beginner and try to learn...   how to change it to work? how to get the line from the text where is the string found?

Comment: take some course ... start with something simpler ... read the docuemntation ...

Comment: I searched a lot today that`s why I am asking for help....

Comment: if `s` is supposed to be a nullable string, I'd try `if ((s?.Contains(flag) == true))` // untested

Answer (score 0):

I think you what to add "?" on s

to be like this:

```
if ((s?.Contains(flag) == true))
{ 
//..
```